# Back Button/history.go() Behavior in Different Browsers

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, internet-explorer

I am loading the Google Maps API on a web page. Each icon I put on the map has an infowindow that, when clicked, submits a form. The form submits to a server script that displays some data. This server form has a button that takes the user back to the map using `history.go(-1)`.

When `history.go(-1)`directs back to the map page in Firefox and Chrome, the map is in the same state it was in when the form was submitted. However, in IE, the map page completely reloads when `history.go(-1)` is executed. I'd like to prevent the page refresh that IE is doing with`history.go(-1)`.

How can I prevent IE from completely reloading the page?

Comment: put the data into session storage? or just serve the form again without using `history.go`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by serving the form again. I just want the map page to display in the state that it was in before I submitted the form in the first place. This is occurring in FF and Chrome but not in IE.